# unix, list all files modified after certain date recursively

Tags: unix

I need to recursively list all files in a directory that were modified after a certain date.  Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848293/shell-script-get-all-files-modified-after-date

Answer (score 7):

```
touch -t YYMMDDhhmm.SS /tmp/timestamp
find directory -type f -newer /tmp/timestamp
rm /tmp/timestamp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`...

```
touch –date "2012-11-07" /tmp/find_after
find / -newer /tmp/find_after
rm /tmp/find_after
```

Comment: works but option should be --date

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
find . -type f -mtime 1
```

this above command will show you files modified 1 day ago from the current directory recursively.